# Google Panda algorithm - site wide or url

Tags: google-panda-algorithm

I recently attended Pubcon, and was told that the Panda algorithm was for each page/url. Does anyone know which is true, is Panda a site wide penalty or just a page penalty?

Comment: Which what is true? Your question is very unclear. Please clarify.

Comment: edited, i hope that is clear enough for you now.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any penalty that is page by page- that would be just plain bad performance.

Panda is site-wide aimed at very specific types of activities; ad to content ratio and content below the fold, many pages with no content primarily navigational, content redundancy/overlap/duplication, excessive affiliate marketing, generally low content quality, excessively high bounce rates (back to the SERP), excessive use of doorway pages, use of spinners, article marketing, scraped content, excessive automation, and so on.

Be wary of people with too much SEO wisdom. There are a lot of them out there.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I thought Panda was, before I heard this url penalty.

Comment: I laughed at the irony of the last line as I typed it. It seems that I give SEO advice here a lot. Mostly because of all the SEO junk on the web and people parrot. There is good stuff too of course. But the plethora of -me to- junk topic de' jure out there and the serious gyrations recommended is absolutely ridiculous. SEO is absolutely the simplest thing you can do. Really. There are no magic buttons to push or levers to pull. No special combination that unlocks performance. Just common sense and a few things to do and you will perform as you should.

Comment: Agreed, I have been in the game from 96, and seen a lot of ups and downs, way out theories, and smart tactics. But now my view is far more holistic. Design the site around the user - whilst still describing the pages to Google.

Comment: @Source Perfectly said, *Design the site around the user - whilst still describing the pages to Google.* My approach has also gotten a bit more holistic. I take a more sensible top down view of SEO and stay out of the weeds. Staying out of the weeds seems to be the best SEO advice I can think of.